# How to get component class from an native element reference in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript

I have an HTML Div element with angular component children inside the div.
Somehow the angular template is like this.

```html
        <mat-radio-group [(ngModel)]="selectedRadioValue">
          <div
            #radioButtonDiv
            *ngFor="let opt of getInputPayload(); index as optIndex"
          >
            <mat-radio-button [value]="opt">
              {{ opt.label }}
            </mat-radio-button>
            <ng-container *ngIf="someCondition === true">
              <app-my-component [attr]="opt.foo"></app-my-component>
            </ng-container>
          </div>
        </mat-radio-group>
```

I got the outer div element ref using `@ViewChildren`

```js
  @ViewChildren('radioButtonDiv') radioButtonDiv: QueryList<ElementRef<HTMLDivElement>>;
```

How do I access the `<app-my-component>` component class inside `radioButtonDiv` QueryList?

I tried to use `querySelector()` from the outer div's nativeElement.

```js
        this.radioButtonDiv.forEach((rbd, index) => {
          if (index === findIndex) {
            // Ignore the setTimeout.
            setTimeout(() => {
              const findChild = rbd.nativeElement.querySelector('app-formulir-medis-attribute');
            }, 500);
          }
        });
```

However, `findChild` result in above code showing the nativeElement of `<my-component>` Component not the Angular component, thus I couldn't access its attributes and properties. How do I get the MyComponent class from the element ref above?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can use ContentChild or ng-contetnt tag.
[here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-5zwv6k?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fpayment.component.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html,src%2Fapp%2Fpayment.component.html,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.module.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.css) is a stackblitz example.

Answer (score 0):

To access the `<app-my-component>` component class rather than the DOM element, you can use `@ViewChildren` with the component class as the selector.

So, if the component class is `MyComponent`, it would look like this:

```
@ViewChildren(MyComponent) myComponents!: QueryList<MyComponent>;
```

[Here's a StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-p45fwo?file=src/main.ts) showing this approach.